# How to choose first element from one list and the corresponding element from the other nested list

Tags: list, for-loop

I have a two lists. 
One is just a regular list where the elements are just numbers and the other list is a nested list and elements are urls for pictures.

For example,

```
#a regular list
id=[100, 200, 300, ...] 

#a nested list
urls=[['http://www.a.jpg','http://www.b.jpg','http://www.c.jpg'],
['http://www.dd.jpg','http://www.ee.jpg'],
['http://www.fff.jpg','http://www.gggg.jpg','http://www.hhhh.jpg']]
```

My goal is to use a for loop and iterate through each element from nested list for each element in a regular list. For example, when I build a loop going through each id, I want to also print out the corresponding element within the nested list.

```
Expected code for this would be:
for i in id:
    #here I need to print out each element from the nested list
...
```

```
Expected output:
100, ['http://www.a.jpg','http://www.b.jpg','http://www.c.jpg']
200, ['http://www.dd.jpg','http://www.ee.jpg']
300, ['http://www.fff.jpg','http://www.gggg.jpg','http://www.hhhh.jpg']
```

The other parts of the codes for saving images from url and putting into a local computer is almost there but I keep iterating through a wrong elements or duplicates. I've been spending so much time..please can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like (e.g. in Python)

```
for i in range(0, len(id)):
    print(id[i], "," , urls[i])
```